# Is CSS Grid Not Woking on Android 4.0 - 5.0?

Tags: android, css, grid, css-grid

I am styling my website with css grid. It works fine in standard browser in my computer. But, in my mobile device (android 5) is not work properly. My website is not displaying a grid design. Its displaying just single column.

I am stuck on this. Please help. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  background: #2196F3;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
.grid-item:nth-child(odd) {
    background: red;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(even) {
    background: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>  
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>  
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The default browsers in Android 4 & 5 likely don't support Grid Layout. https://caniuse.com/#search=grid (click "Show all" for more details)

Comment: @Michael_B Oh, thanks for the information, very helpful.